# Pyspark job on Dataproc gets stuck at stage 0

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I've a Dataproc cluster with 2 worker nodes. My pyspark program is very simple

1) Reads a 500MB data from Bigquery 
2) Apply a few UDFs 
3) Display results from pyspark SQL dataframe based on some condition

At the third step the jobs gets stuck at stage 0 and does nothing. I'm new to Pyspark but I don't think so the data is huge for it to get hanged. Please help me.

@Adam,

My UDF is from RDkit library. Is it possible to make the UDF efficient so the output is in seconds?

```
from rdkit import Chem

user_smile_string = 'ONC(=O)c1ccc(I)cc1' 
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(user_smile_string)

def Matched(smile_structure):
    try:
        match = mol.HasSubstructMatch(Chem.MolFromSmiles(smile_structure))
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        return (match)
```

Comment: Since .show() (the display of the df) is the action, which triggers the transformations, there could be a problem with the UDF's, but this hard to estimate without knowing the actual code, or error message.

Comment: Did you check the resource manager and node manager logs? On a Dataproc VM these are under `/var/logs/hadoop-yarn/`

Comment: You can check DAG to know where exactly execution stuck. Sometimes input dataset is small, however it becomes huge after several operations like join.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to troubleshoot your job to understand what's happening.

You can start from exploring [job driver output](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/driver-output), [job logs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/stackdriver-logging#accessing_job_logs_in) and [Spark job DAG](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways#creating_a_cluster_with_component_gateway) that are accessible from Google Cloud UI.

If this will not yield any useful information, then you need to [enable debug logging](https://mapr.com/support/s/article/Spark-Troubleshooting-guide-Debugging-Spark-Applications-How-to-pass-log4j-properties-from-executor-and-driver?language=en_US) in Spark and go from there.

Comment: Also, you can look at the YARN web UI to see if there is pending resource allocation. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways#viewing_and_accessing_component_gateway_urls